# Export Table as Excel file in php

Tags: php, html

CSS is effecting in UI but not in Excel. Anyone can help me on this please.

Below code will export table into excel but not able to provide space before  tags.

```
<?php 
    echo $excel_data = '<table border="1">
        <thead>
            <th align="left">S.No.</th>
            <th align="left">Name</th>
            <th align="left">DOJ</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">1</td>
                <td align="left">Sreekanth Kuriyala</td>
                <td align="left">04-06-2015</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">2</td>
                <td style="padding-left:20px;">SK</td>
                <td align="left">26-07-2015</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>';
    $excel_file = 'Reports.xls';
    file_put_contents ($excel_file, $excel_data);
?>
</br>
</br>
<a href="<?php echo $excel_file; ?>" download>Export to Excel</a>
```

Comment: I ran this and didn't see a problem.  What does it mean, "not able to provide space before tags"?  There's no CSS here; is that relevant?

Comment: I added css to <td> tag. For one of the td tag i given padding-left:20px but this padding is not taking effect in .xls file

Comment: You can but $nbsp; in to add spaces.  I tried it and it worked.  IDK if there's a way to save formatting using `file_put_contents`.

Answer (score -1):

you have to create a CSV file just create new php file with a function that expects a result of a db select.

then just echo cols separated by ; and carrier return for next row.

this is a function i made:

```
<?php
function printcsv($result){
                  //result of database select 
header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.csv');
echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";
$nl = "\n";
//this will be the carrier return var
    if($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
        while($rs != ''){
            echo $rs[0].";".$rs[1].";".$rs[2].";".$rs[3].";".$rs[4].";".$rs[5].";".$nl;
            $rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

change my mysqli_fetch_array by your result desired fetch and try it =)

oh, and you cannot write tables on it, only echo data separated by semicolon. each data for each column, semicolon to put the next data in next column, and carrier return to write in next row.

cheers!

Comment: Thanks Joel. But in my case i have to export Table as Excel file with extension .xls. Am able to export it but not able to apply spaces in  <td> tags

Comment: csv is excel file, anyway if you need xls, use the same changing content-type header to: content-type application/xlsx.
i dont know if it takes values separated by semicolon too or if it uses another separator, check it and you get it  =)

Comment: PD: i dont know exactly how have to ve parsed to echo a xls file but i'm pretty sure that you cannot echo a table and pretend to store it in xls format. if i'm not wrong, it's a XML-based format, so you'll need to echo a csv estructure.